# AWS Lambda Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I created a simple Node.js script to connect to a RDS instance but sadly it always returns with timeout error. It is strange because it works perfectly from my machine.

The instance is public accessible and context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

have you got any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Lambda has a property of time out. Have you checked this configuration in the Lambda via console (Basic configuration) or in your deployment template file?

Comment: I reconfigured it several times (from 3 secs to 60secs) but nothing...and I don't do any complicated things just connect and insert some test data

Comment: @user1393317 what u did?

Answer (score 1):

i have same error i fix with incress the timeout time

new aws UI

```
lambda function -> configuration -> General configuration -> Edit Timeout
```

[image]